# Possible to Transfer $scope values to another Controller in ng-repeat items?

Tags: angularjs

I have listed items using ng-repeat you can see the example below. I am adding a function where when you click on the item a modal will be displayed with more details about said list item. 
As a result i wonder if there is a way where i can transfer the Data from the List item into the Controller without having to query the api again?

HTML

```
<div class="project-item" ng-controller="openProjectsCtrl">
    <ol>
        <li class="list-item" data-ng-click="showModal()" data-ng-repeat="project in projects | orderBy:'Posted' : true">
            <h4>{{project.Title}}</h4>
            {{project.Skills}}<br/>
            <div>
                <span>{{project.Budget}}</span>
                <span class="pull-right timestamp">{{project.Posted|timeago}}</span>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

Current $http controller for repeat:

```
app.controller('openProjectsCtrl', function ($scope, $http, myModal) {

  $http.get("http://localhost/app/controllers/php/getProjects.php")
  .success(function (response) {$scope.projects = response.projects;});

  $scope.showModal = myModal.activate;

});
```

And the Modal itself is just another Partial.

So to sum up i would like to take the variables:

- project.Title
- project.Skills
- project.Budget
- project.Posted

and transfer those values so i can use inside the modal the same way:
    
        {{project.x}}

Comment: You could have a service that is caching your data and inject this service in the modal controller.

Answer (score 0):

You should create another service for this one. And for caching your data you can refer this service in angular - $cacheFactory.

In your app.js,

```
app.factory('myCache', function($cacheFactory){
    return $cacheFactory('myData');
});
```

For storing the data in cache, in your 'openProjectsCtrl' - you should inject this 'myCache' then,

```
 myCache.put('myData', response.projects);
```

In the controller where you need to use this data, you should inject 'myCache' factory. then you can retrieve that data using,

```
    $scope.cache = timelineCache.get('myData');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
myApp.factory('CacheScopeData', function{
  var scopeData=null;
  var setScopedata=function(data){
   scopeData=data;
  },
  var getScopedata=function(){
   return scopeData;
  }
});
```

Set scope data in one controller using **setScopedata** methode  and get back data in other controller using **getScopedata**.

Comment: You can try these both methods. If you need to store your data in cache, then you can go for my answer. Otherwise, you can use this method.         @Elevant

Comment: I tried using this method but i was getting a getScopedata not define error. @VirtualRealist

Comment: Did you added CacheScopeData service as dependency injection in controller .?   If not then do this way.           app.controller('openProjectsCtrl', function ($scope, $http, myModal, CacheScopeData ) {...});

Comment: yeah i did  i will try again

Comment: Ohk.. try again. @Elevant

Comment: Yeah so when trying to do:
var listitem = getScopedata();
    console.log(listitem); i get the error:
getScopedata is not defined

Comment: try this.. var listitem = CacheScopeData.getScopedata();

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80891/discussion-between-chirag-and-elevant).

Answer (score 0):

Good morning , and possible use factory for the realization of this service fast, you CAN CREATE " setters and getters " to receive and return the object OR variable . Below follows o Example ...

```
app.factory('armazenaCliente', function() {

//Create object
var cliente = new Cliente();

//Create setters and getters
return {
    setCliente : function(cli) {
        cliente = cli;
    },
    getCliente : function() {
        return cliente;
    }
 };
});
```

you should reference in Their controllers to be able to use...

```
  controller('ActivityDemoCtrl',
        [ '$scope', 'armazenaCliente', function($scope, armazenaCliente) {
           ....
           }]);
```

From the statement already you can use the " setters and getters " designed to perform the manipulation .

```
armazenaCliente.setCliente(cliente);
$scope.recuperaCliente = armazenaCliente.getCliente();
```

I hope this helps ....